# What you get the levels after 8?

Tags: ingress

Until recently, level 8 was the maximum level in Ingress, but now there are more levels. What are the benefits when you level after level 8? I think there aren't any higher resonators or bursters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no higher resonators than 8 but if you get above level 8 you will get some benefits.

I found nice infographics about it here: https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/hJdabxHHmYD

[image]

Comment: In case someone is wondering, like I was, the hexagons represent badges you need to reach a level. Silver, gold and the one above respective.

Comment: Bronze > Silver > Gold > Platinum > Onyx/Black

Comment: This is fine, but it really only tells you 2 things.  XM capacity and recharge range.  what about other things?  Portal submission (level 10), OPR access (level 12), etc?